# Unable to copy to Windows container ('docker cp') on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, hyper-v, windows-container

I set up Docker for Windows on my laptop and switched from *Linux Containers* to *Windows Containers* in Docker's settings (which prompted a couple of restarts and Windows updates). I pulled an image and ran a container based on it using the commands:

```
docker pull microsoft/dotnet-framework
docker run -it microsoft/dotnet-framework cmd
```

In a second terminal window, I executed the command:

```
docker cp app container_id:/
```

and received this error message:

> Error response from daemon: filesystem operations against a running Hyper-V container are not supported

I googled this error, but nothing (explanatory) came up, quite surprisingly. Is there a way I can run the image as a Windows container rather than a Hyper-V container, on Windows 10?

Ultimately, I will deploy this container to a Windows Server 2016 host, but I need to do all development and testing in my laptop running Windows 10 Pro.

Docker Version

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 22:19:00 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Comment: So does this thing work in Windows 2016?

Comment: Error was descriptive. Since you run it on Windows 10 you can not run in any other isolation other then Hyper-V. If you deploy it on Windows 2016 then you can run it in `process` isolation and will not have this issue.

Comment: Thanks @GregorySuvalian ... I was able to get around the issue by stopping the container, running the `docker cp` command and then restarting the container. It is relatively just an inconvenience, but I was able to get past the issue when I looked at the error again closely.

Comment: I would recommend using scp to copy between host and container

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Based on a comment by @GregorySuvalian, I understand that Windows 10 allows Hyper-V runtime only. So my workaround is to stop the container, running the `docker cp` command and restart the container. (I preferred this over setting up a volume, since it is just a one time operation.)

Comment: For people wanting to mount the host folder into the container, it worked for me to add this to my docker run command: `--mount type=bind,source="c:/host/folder/path/with/forward/slashes",target="C:/container/folder/path/with/forward/slashes"`.

Answer (score 4):

Edit to Vimes answer as I had a difficult time to use the `--mount` within my docker run commmand. The actual run command needs to be within the quotes `''` starting from `type...`

`--mount 'type=bind,source="c:/host/folder/path/with/forward/slashes",target="C:/container/folder/path/with/forward/slashes"'`